# Rigidbody2D и Box Collider2d

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть 2 объекта, на которых висят Rigidbody2D и Box Collider2d также есть скрипт

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other){
        Debug.Log("collision");
    }
```

Но когда происходит столкновение в консоль ничего не выводиться,
данная функция работает только когда на объектах висят  Rigidbody и Box Collider
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы используете компоненты 2D физики (Rigidbody2D и BoxСollider2d), но в вашем коде метод для 3D физики. В случае 2D объектов используйте аналогичные методы для 2D, например: [OnCollisionEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html)