# Заморозка движения объектов в unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно при соприкосновении заморозить движение объектов.
С заморозкой движения одного объекта я бы и сам справился , но вот есть ли возможность заморозить движения всех объектов , но не их скрипты + изменение цвета с анимацией также должны работать . 
Думал над `Time.timeScale = 0` , но не уверен будет ли работать ,то что описано выше.
Если же нет легкого способа так сделать , то лучше уж просто заморозить движение объекта.

Будет ли работать `Time.timeScale = 0` так как нужно , если же нет то что стоит здесь сделать?

Comment: Проверил, Time.timeScale = 0 не работает так как нужно.

Comment: Попробуйте `Time.fixedDeltaTime`.

Comment: У rigidbody есть набор атрибутов для заморозки положения и вращения

Comment: @Stranger in the Q А если у объекта нету rigidbody , а только collider.

Comment: @Veudd а как они тогда двигаются?

Comment: @Veudd значит нужно запрещать движение в скрипте, который висит на объекте. Вы ведь как-то объекты эти двигаете, верно?

Comment: @Veudd событие "столкновения" можно отлавливать с помощью метода `OnCollisionEnter2D`, о котором вы можете почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/818214/rigidbody2d-и-box-collider2d/818220#818220) или [здесь](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html)

Comment: Событие "столкновения" я уже отслеживаю с помощью метода OnCollisionEnter2D.

Comment: Запрещать движение объектов в скрипте я могу ,просто боюсь не будет ли сильная нагрузка идти(Мне нужно искать объекты , а потом скрипт на них что бы передать значение ,а их у меня так то немало).

Comment: @Veudd вы ищете объект на сцене (`GameObject.Find`)? если так, то, мне кажется, это неверно и есть гораздо более лучший способ "поиска"

Comment: @Stranger in the Q одни с помощью  transform.position , другие оборачиваются с помощью  transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 50f * Time.deltaTime);

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94461/discussion-between-mikhail-deyman-and-veudd).

Comment: Ответ был дан пользователем Mikhail Deyman.Решить проблему можно с помощью событий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:
1. в скрипте, который висит на  объекте, что останавливает все Move-объекты (объекты которые двигаются), объявите событие:

```
public static event OnCollisionEvent = delegate { };
```

("static" позволит обращаться напрямую к этому событию из любого места)
2. в Move, где-нибудь сделайте метод, который будет содержать логику "остановки" данного объекта
3. в том же Move, где-нибудь в методе Start() вы должны будете подписать ваш Move-объект на глобальное событие остановки. Сделать это можно с помощью следующей строчки:

```
НазваниеВашегоСкрипта.OnCollisionEvent += НазваниеВашегоМетодаОстановки;
```

Таким образом, на этот момент, все ваши Move-объекты с момента отработки метода Start будут "слушать" и ждать события OnCollisionEvent
следовательно, вам осталось только вовремя вызвать это событие - а вместе с ним и всех "подписчиков", который следят за событием
4. вызываем событие в том самом скрипте, в методе столкновения (OnCollisionEnter2D) так:

```
OnCollisionEvent();
```

Если будут непонятки с синтаксисом, т.е. с самим написанием кода - погуглите про "события C#" или, например, тут простым языком описано и показано - https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.14.php.
Ответ был дан пользователем Mikhail Deyman.